# document.getElementById is not working in js

Tags: javascript

I have a table :

```
<tr>

    <td><input type="text" name="remaining_quantity" id="remaining_quantity" value="<?php if(isset($quantity)) echo $quantity; ?>"/></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="remaining_price" id="remaining_price" value="<?php if(isset($price)) echo $price; ?>" /></td>

    <input type="button" class="check fr ml" value="Check" id="check_equation" onclick="get_full_status()" />

</tr>
```

I want to find the value to input field so,

```
function get_full_status(){
    var remaining_quantity = document.getElementById('remaining_quantity').value;
    var remaining_price = document.getElementById('remaining_price').value;
    alert(remaining_quantity);alert(remaining_price);
}
```

I don't get actual value. If u don't understand question ask me.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? What values the alert return?

Comment: There is no error in console. It alerts blank.

Comment: Did you check the `value` attribute? *Does* it have any value in it?

Comment: With no errors it means that `getElementById()` works just fine. What are the values of `$quantity` and `$price`? Are the `value=""` attributes empty when you render the template?

Comment: yes value have integer value

Answer (score -1):

I checked the samething on jsfiddle and it is working fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/b13gtff0/

```
function get_full_status(){
            var remaining_quantity = document.getElementById('remaining_quantity').value;
            var remaining_price = document.getElementById('remaining_price').value;
            alert(remaining_quantity);alert(remaining_price);
}
```

I feel like here the issue could be server is not returning any value.
Or may be some php syntax issues.
My suggestion would be can you please check the response which is returned from server.

Also are you seeing any exceptions when you click on button in console.

Comment: Here is no error in jsfiddle but I got problms in my code

Comment: Who down vote? if u dare the answer the question.. We all knw giving answer is far easy to downvote

Comment: Regis , then you downvoted the incorrect one.
You should have downvoted the question but not the answer.

Comment: yes. I probably clicked on the question's downvote button while your answer was appearing on screen. It might be a stackoverflow bug. If you edit your answer, my downvote will go.